# How to play .m3u8 Stream Using jwplayer in phonegap Android?

Tags: android, cordova, jwplayer, http-live-streaming, live-streaming

i am using phonegap for http live streaming i am using jwplayer for it.

here is the code for it..

```
 <div id='mediaplayer1'> 
                <script type="text/javascript">  jwplayer('mediaplayer1').setup({
                   'id': 'playerID', 'width': '388',    'height': '218',
                'provider': 'rtmp',  
                 'streamer': 'rtmp://myserver/chk',
                'autostart': 'true',
                'stretching': 'exactfit',

                        levels: [{
                                   bitrate: "800",
                                   file: "file-super",
                                   width: "1280"
                               }],    
                'modes': [
                       {type: 'flash', src: 'http://www.myserver.com/jwplayer/player.swf'},
                       {
                         type: 'html5',
                         config: {
                          levels: [ {'file': 'http://myserver/playlist.m3u8'} ],
                          'provider': 'video'
                         }
                       }
                   ]
                 });</script>

                    </div>
```

and in head

```
<script src="jwplayer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

i want to play .m3u8 url.
some times video play for about 1 or 2 sec. and automatically stops.
and some times show warning no playable resource found.
how to resolve this. is there any good example/tutorial for it.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Is there an example you can provide that we can debug?

Comment: Which Android version are you using? I have a related, although slightly different, question open (http://goo.gl/2u0yR) and in testing it I've found a huge variation of support for HLS across different Android versions. In my testing, Android 4.0 seemed to be significantly better at handling HLS than either 3.0 or 4.2.

Comment: @HaemEternal my minsdkversion is 15 and targetsdkversion is 17 and device is samsung galaxy tab2 7"

Comment: @EthanLongTail for example we can use "http://nasahd-i.akamaihd.net/hls/live/203739/NASATV1_iOS_HD/Edge.m3u8" i have tested it on http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw-player/wizard/ also but same error..

Comment: Well, the Wizard uses a free copy of the JW Player. You need to use JW Player premium in order for HLS to work. You might want to also consider using Akamai's provider for this, but this is a Flash only provider, so I don't think it will work in Android - http://mediapm.edgesuite.net/jw/

Comment: Hi, could you solve it? I have the exactly same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Vitamio](https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle/tree/v3.0) Player it can play all kind of streaming also its open source,.
u just need to include this as library into ur project and make sure to use vitamio videoview or mediaplayer,. k no worry take a look at this [Sample](https://github.com/yixia/VitamioDemo) to include Vitamio into ur project

Hope its Helps you,.

Answer (score 0):

Simply the streaming video can be opened up in a child browser or in App browser to play the video. This solution will work both on Android as well as iOS.

Also if the streaming will be opened in the browser it will appear in full screen mode as q media player will play the video on safari.

Hope this will help.

Comment: .you mean we can open the m3u8 url on in app browser in android and it willl play?